# Как получить ID записи в БД при клике на кнопку в айтеме списка

Tags: java, android-layout

Нужно выводить список товаров с бд приложения. Пишу такое (код упрощен):

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);

       scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout, null, from, to, 0);

       lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

       registerForContextMenu(lvData);

       getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

где `rowlayout` помимо текста есть еще две кнопки

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Open in browser"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="openTable"
    />
```

При клике на которую нужно открывать таблицу.

Подскажите, как можно получить `item_id` (то есть тот в котором находиться кнопка) и как потом передать этот `id` в следующую активити и там уже сделать еще один запрос в бд и вывести таблицу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы обработать клик на вложенных в айтем элементах, вам необходимо использовать кастомный адаптер списка - привязка метода обработки клика в разметке тут не подходит для решения такой задачи.
Поскольку вы используете стандартный `SimpleCursorAdapter`, то переделка потребуется минимальная - переопределить метод `bindView()` этого адаптера, чтобы он реагировал на клики по вложенным элементам:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        Button button2 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")); 
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID", id);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Здесь мы привязываем к кнопке на разметке айтема с id = *button2* слушатель, при клике на эту кнопку будет вызвана активити - `SomeActivity`, в качестве аргумента ей будет передан *ID* записи из БД, на которой была нажата кнопка.
Чтобы получить значение *ID* в нашей `SomeActivity` нужно проделать нехитрую манипуляцию по извлечению значения из отправленного интента:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
        long ID = getIntent().getLongExtra("ID", -1); // -1 - значение по умолчанию, если ничего не получено.

        ...
    }

}
```

Кроме того, вам нужно изменить используемый адаптер с `SimpleCursorAdapter` на созданный вами `CustomAdapter` (название, естественно может быть более уместным):

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);

       scAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout, null, from, to, 0);

       lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

       registerForContextMenu(lvData);

       getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

Все готово.
Замечу, что при использовании кликабельных элементов внутри айтема, могут появится нежелательные проблемы с фокусом каждого элемента, так как имеется конкуренция.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш способ прекрасно работает. Подскажете как бороться с "нежелательные проблемы с фокусом каждого элемента, так как имеется конкуренция" ?