# Как передать объект из листвью?

Tags: android, база-данных, android-studio, sqlite, listview

Как передать нажатый элемент списка ListView в другую активити в курсор с формулой Select Колонка_2 from Таблица where  колонка_1 ='a' через интент? Вместо А - должен быть нажатый элемент списка в ListView.

Comment: Почему используешь Intent?

Comment: Что бы передать в другую активити

Comment: Тогда используй методы `intent.putExtra()` и `intent.getStringExtra()`

Comment: Выдает ошибку android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor cannot be cast to com.example.myapplication1.string

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457016/177345

Comment: Не видя код, сложно ответить на твой вопрос. Залей в репозиторий и дай ссылку

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N0oSh40X3j26Fn7diqYZPya3hPImwN1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: В [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345) реализация с передачей объекта из ListView с заполнением из БД в активити

Comment: Не совсем понимаю ответ. Мне нужно , что бы при нажатии элемента в ListView на активити1,заполненная колонкой1,  открывалась активити2 ,заполненная колонкой 2, где с фильтром по нажатому элементу колонки 1

Comment: Вам нужно передавать во вторую активити не выборку из БД по фильтру, а то, что является фильтром (строку, число и т.п.) и во второй активити делать уже выборку из БД по полученному значению и отображать в списке